# Issues creating folder using boost::filesystem

Tags: c++, boost, visual-studio-2015, directory, win-universal-app

I'm attempting to create a folder using boost how ever when compiled I get the following errors.

```
1>c:\program files (x86)\boost_1_60_0\boost\filesystem\path.hpp(458):error C2059: syntax error: 'generic'

1>c:\program files (x86)\boost_1_60_0\boost\filesystem\path.hpp(459): error C2334: unexpected token(s) preceding '{'; skipping apparent function body
```

The above errors mention path.hpp so I'm wondering if it's an issue with the header or my code?

```
#include "pch.h"
#include "Information.h" 
#include <iostream> // forgot to include this when I typed up the question
#include "boost\filesystem.hpp"

User::User() // Constructor
{

}

User::~User() // Destructor
{

}


void User::Setup() 
{
    boost::filesystem::path Dir("C:\\Users\\Public\\Documents\\Temp\\Private\\");
    if(boost::filesystem::create_directories(Dir))
    {
       std::cout << "Sucess: " << std::endl;
    }
}
```

The program is being worked on in visual studio 2015 as an universal windows app targeting windows 10. The paths for boost were correctly added to additional include directories and linker path etc..

Comment: Including a single boost header like that is probably not what you want. It will try to include other boost headers like this: `#include <boost/filesystem/config.hpp>` which won't work, unless boost is in your include path already.

Comment: Boost is in my include path :) and I attempted to just use specific headers such as path.hpp but I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: @melak47 to verify that they were added correctly lol, I realize if it wasn't I would get an error for it but since I couldn't understand why it wasn't working I tried the full path as well as your suggestion both produce the same result. And these are most certainly the only errors.

Comment: I've checked every thing including the boost header in question (path.hpp) I've found no issues, and continue to get those two errors. That being said I've found that by default universal windows apps import various windows namespaces at this point and due to the fact that I've tested this same code in other compilers and general win 32 projects it seems that one of the said namespaces is conflicting... Because this code works every where else

Comment: Sorry, I entirely missed the bit about this being a *Universal App*. Universal apps use Microsoft's C++/CX, and `generic` happens to be a keyword there. You could probably keep "problematic" (standard compliant ._.) code like this gated behind a plain Win32 C++ static library that doesn't drag it into it's headers. On a different note, using Boost.Filesystem in a universal app means it probably won't work universally :)

Comment: Compiler issues notwithstanding, you shouldn't have write access to that folder unless you've changed the ACLs on the filesystem.

Answer (score 0):

@melak47

> Sorry, I entirely missed the bit about this being a Universal App. Universal apps use Microsoft's C++/CX, and generic happens to be a keyword there. You could probably keep "problematic" (standard compliant ._.) code like this gated behind a plain Win32 C++ static library that doesn't drag it into it's headers. On a different note, using Boost.Filesystem in a universal app means it probably won't work universally :)

Problem was resolved

I was able to " gate it " and fix it! Yeah haha I know it wouldn't work universally I was just messing around with it I don't really develop for windows that often figured I'd give it a shot.